# Strange bug when renaming a file with NSFileManager

Tags: file, copy, plist, rename, nsfilemanager

I used to use the following to rename aplist file with various user inputted values (BOOL,Strings mostly):

```
    [manager moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error];
```

And for some reason in iOS4+ this glitches out, so I Attempt the following:

```
 [1]  [manager copyItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error];
 [2]  [manager removeItemAtPath:oldPath error:&error];
```

Now, [1] copies the plist and ALL of the data correctly. (I've verified when commenting out [2]. But for some reason, when I attempt [1] & [2], the file /appears/ renamed, however, there are only certain fields missing, for example I FName and LName stay intact, whereas Phone1,Phone2,Email1,Email2 and Website are removed from the new file.

**For the life of me, I just cannot figure out why only some of the data remains when I attempt a removeFileAtPath for the OLD file AFTER the NEW FILE is created?**

Any help would be MUCH APPRECIATED!

I just simply want to rename a plist file, while keeping ALL of the data in tact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *newPath = [[oldPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:newFilename];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] movePath:oldPath toPath:newPath handler:nil];
```